# CSS - Is it possible to force a <th> to take up an entire row?

Tags: css

This is rather unconventional, but this is a choice between re-writing pages of HTML or finding a way to do it in CSS. I would like a `<th>` to take up an entire row, forcing the one `<td>` which follows it to be on the next row (so a `<th></th> <td></td>` becomes a single column instead of two).

I have tried display: block, but that doesn't seem to cut it. What should I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, as `rowspan` and `colspan` have no CSS equivalent.

It can't be done using the `:after` pseudo-class, because you can't add markup that way, only node content. (right?)

The only idea that comes to mind, if the first column has a class name, you could try

```
th { display: none }
th.firstcolumn { display: table-cell }
```

and see what happens. I think, however, that this will *not* cause the `th` to spread over every column, just hide the others.

Oh and an *extremely* nasty idea, something along the lines of

```
th { display: none }
th.firstcolumn { position: absolute; display: block; left: 0px; right: 0px; }
```

but before you resort to that, you may want to rewrite your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no css property as of today that allows you to set table-cell properties such as colspan.

I would just do a search/replace in your IDE to replace `<th>` tags with `<th colspan="2">`

Should take mere seconds to do it.

Based on OP's edit:

I would try replacing every occurrence of `</th>` with `</th></tr><tr>`, that way you will get your desired effect of splitting the back to back  as described.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with script, if you have ids on the header cells.

```
var header = document.getElementById("header_cell_id");
header.colSpan = "2";
```

I have been trying this with jQuery (which would be better) but it doesn't seem to work for some reason:

```
$("th").attr("colspan", "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible — and, I’d venture, shouldn’t be possible. You should get your HTML right. It sounds like your `<th>` should have a `scope` attribute indicating which cells it’s a heading for.